# Cant Set Any Header in Fetch Get Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, fetch

Im trying to send a get Request from the browser to my backend (node + express). But somehow my headers dont seem to get set.

Heres the Frontend:

```
let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/checkLogin', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: same-origin,

        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'X-Test':'test'
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

In the backend i tried to enable custom headers:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
console.log("CORS");
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:3000/testLogin');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type, X-Test');
next();});
```

I already tried the answers of similar questions but none of them worked.

when i print the headers received by the server i get:

```
host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
```

Comment: ill undo my edit sorry

Comment: You should be getting some indication from the browser why the response wasn't allowed. You should also look into using the [`cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) rather than rolling your own.

Comment: the cors middleware also doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin you're specifying is invalid. It needs to have a scheme (e.g., `http://` or `https://`). Also note that origins don't have paths. So for instance, instead of `'localhost:3000/testLogin'`, it would be `'http://localhost:3000'`:

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: @TimmNicolaizik - Doh! We've all done that sort of thing. :-) Glad you figured it out!